# Can I transfer from Pokémon Moon back to Pokémon X?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation, pokemon-bank, pokemon-seventh-generation

I have tried to use Pokébank to transfer xerneas from Moon back to X. Is there a way to do this? I need to transfer back.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately No.

Pokemon X is a Generation 6 game, Pokemon Sun is Generation 7. One-way transfer exists for moving your Pokemon from Gen 6 to Gen 7 but the reverse is not possible.

Here's a visual guide for using the Pokemon Bank with various Pokemon games, from the [Official Pokemon site](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-video-games/pokemon-bank/):

[image: Pokemon Bank Guide]

As you can see, once a Pokemon is on to Sun/Moon or Ultra Sun/Moon, it can't go to an earlier generation game.